# How to simply introduce a new method on a large subset of classes implementing an interface?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have an interface, say IVehicle, which is implemented in 100s of classes, some of them are variety of 4 wheeler and some are two wheeler dervied types.

I need to introduce a new method for all the 4 wheeler classes, lets say there are 50 of them. My challenge is to reduce the effort as much as I can.

I suggested, to introduce a new interface / abstract class with a method definition. But this require to change every 4 wheeler class declaration and extend with an extra parent.

Is there any possible way?

Comment: There is, but it's kinda ugly and more of a duct tape solution. For something clean, I think you need to go the hard way. Btw, it depends on the language features as well, if it supports something like extension methods

Comment: you don't explain which kind of solution you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am looking for Java and C# both. I too thought of having extension methods, but I believe to declare extension methods for 4 wheeler, we need to provide the base type of it, which in this case is same as that of 2 wheeler.

Comment: Does the new method only use public members?  If so, create a static method in a different utility class that can perform the computation with your interface as a parameter.  In some languages (C#) you can call these like instance methods using a feature called extension methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to avoid changing all those classes and want a solution that can be considered to be OO, one thing you can do is decorate those classes where they are used and need this extra behaviour.

I'll use C# for example code as you mentioned you're looking for C#/Java solution.

```
interface IVehicle
{
    void DoThisNormalThing();
    // ...
}

interface IBetterVehicle : IVehicle
{
    void DoThisNeatThing();
}

class FourWheelVehicle : IVehicle
{
    public void DoThisNormalThing()
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}

class BetterFourWheelVehicle : IBetterVehicle
{
    private readonly _vehicle;

    public BetterFourWheelVehicle(IVehicle vehicle)
    {
        _vehicle = vehicle;
    }

    public void DoThisNormalThing()
    {
        _vehicle.DoThisNormalThing();
    }

    public void DoThisNeatThing()
    {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Then usage:

```
var vehicle = new FourWheelVehicle();
var betterVehicle = new BetterFourWheelVehicle(vehicle);
betterVehicle.DoThisNeatThing();
```

This can be done using extension methods as well (and would result in a little less code and fewer allocated objects), but as this question is tagged with [oop] I wouldn't say extension methods are an OO construct. They're much more aligned with procedural style as they turn your objects into bags of procedures.